# How to correctly install Nvidia GPU Drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, dpkg, display-resolution

I'm new to linux and just installed KDE Neon which is based on `Ubuntu LTS`. I really need help.

The UI is lagging in my computer so I installed `preload`. But now I also want to install the latest nvidia graphics drivers without any problems, how do I install it correctly without any issues?

- GPU: GeForce GTX 1650
- My Monitor resolution: 1920x1080
- Monitor Refresh rate: 75Hz

Thank you in advanced. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: KDE Neon is not an official Ubuntu derivative. Off-topic here. As a courtesy I can suggest opening Additional Drivers, select the recommended version, apply and reboot. Of course, also disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)